# Как из главного файла создать несколько с частью информации главного файла?

Tags: java, eclipse

Проблема такая: нужно из уже созданного файла создать отдельные файлы для каждого из клиентов(customer), при этом в каждом таком файле должна быть информация о Имени,Фамилии,Цене и Количестве.Количество и цену следует дописать в главный файл(придумать) как дополнительные столбцы

public class FileOperations {

static final String DIR_NAME="C:" + File.separator + "outdata" + File.separator; 
    static final String FILE_NAME="output.csv";

```
static File outputDir = new File(DIR_NAME);
static File outputFile = new File(DIR_NAME + FILE_NAME);

public static void save() throws IOException {
    if (outputFile.exists())
        System.out.println("File " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() 
                + " already exists");

    if (!outputDir.exists()) outputDir.mkdirs();

    // true - adds data, false - replaces
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputFile, false);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write("number;firstname;lastname");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("1;\"John\";\"Smith\"");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("2;\"Anne\";\"Brown\"");
    bw.close();
    fw.close(); 
}

public static String[][] readCsvFile(File inFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[][] output = new String[3][4];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
    int i = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String lineOfText = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Line " + i + ": " + lineOfText);
        String[] cells = lineOfText.split(";");
        System.out.println("Cells: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(cells));

        for (int j=0;j<cells.length;j++) {
            output[i][j] = cells[j];
        }
        i++;            
    }

    scanner.close();
    return output;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        save();

        String[][] out = readCsvFile(outputFile);

        for (int i =0;i<out.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Row: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(out[i]));

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File is not writeable: " + e.getMessage());                 
    }

}
```

}
`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то в неком исходной файле лежит информация о клиентах. В качестве решения поставленной проблемы я бы предложил следующий простой порядок действий: 
1) Создать класс Customer, описывающий такой объект как клиент, т.е. со всеми необходимыми полями (имя, фамилия и т.д.) 
2) Считать исходные данные в набор экземпляров этого класса. Тут просто считываешь имя, фамилию, цену, количество. Считав, создаешь экземпляр класса Customer, заполняя его поля. 
3) Когда таким образом обработаешь все данные из исходного файла, дальше можно уже и создавать отдельные файл (в качестве имени файла можно использовать фамилию клиента) и выводить в каждый такой отдельный файл инфу о клиенте.

Конечно, это не самый быстрый способ, но, зато, предельно понятный.